# Android is crashing in certain situation

Tags: java, android, crash

I am in progress of developing an android app. I want to display data by self made class ( entryClass). List is represented by recyclerLayout which include list of cardView such as this. [image]

the description of this ( Lorem Ipsum ...) will be 200 characters + to the end of last word (ex. if 200th character will be just in the middle of word, rest of it will be printed) To achieve this, i made an new method:

```
    public static String cutText(String text){
    String temp="";
    StringBuilder build=new StringBuilder(temp);
    int i=0;
    while((i>200 || text.charAt(i)!=' ') && i<text.length())
    {
        if(text.charAt(i)!='\n'){
        build.append(text.charAt(i));}
        else {build.append(text.charAt(' '));}
        i++;
    }
    return build.toString();
}
```

But when i am using this method, application is crashing while running it. 
This is the part of with added this method:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //creating an cardView
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mAuthorView.setText(mValues.get(position).author);
        holder.mDateView.setText(mValues.get(position).date);
        holder.mContentView.setText(cutText(mValues.get(position).content));
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sadness);
```

When line with cutText method is changed to not contain it, everything is working fine.

I hope that i included everything important.
Best regards!
EDIT:
LOG FROM CRASH:

```
12-21 15:24:05.062 10574-10574/pl.spicyproject.quickstart E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: pl.spicyproject.quickstart, PID: 10574
                                                                        java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
                                                                            at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
                                                                            at pl.spicyproject.quickstart.Home.cutText(Home.java:201)
                                                                            at pl.spicyproject.quickstart.Home$SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Home.java:151)
                                                                            at pl.spicyproject.quickstart.Home$SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Home.java:129)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1732)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1497)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                                            at android.view.View.layout(View.jav
```

12-21 15:24:07.450 10574-10574/pl.spicyproject.quickstart I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10574 SIG: 9

Comment: Please include the logcat from when the crash occurs.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UY41yzuF

Comment: What do you think `text.charAt(' ')` means? (I think it means `text.charAt(32)`).

Comment: Please *include* it in the question, don't link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the string length first in your while loop condition:

```
while(i<text.length() && (i>200 || text.charAt(i)!=' '))
```

since otherwise it might try to call `text.charAt(i)` for `i` beyond the end of the string.

Also:

```
build.append(text.charAt(' '));
```

This will only work if there are at least 33 characters in `text`, since `text.charAt(' ')` is semantically equivalent to `text.charAt(32)`.

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like you are trying to replace newlines with spaces. The following might be easier:

```
text.replace('\n', ' ')
```

---

For your specification, I think that it would be a lot clearer if you used something like the following, which avoids the use of a StringBuilder:

```
String cutText(String text) {
  int i = Math.min(200, text.length());
  while (i < text.length() && text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
    ++i;
  }
  return text.substring(0, i).replace('\n', ' ');
}
```

Comment: i made this changes. App is still crashing.

Comment: In exactly the same way?

Comment: public static String cutText(String text){
        text = text.replace('\n',' ');
        String temp="";
        StringBuilder build=new StringBuilder(temp);
        int i=0;
        while(i<text.length() && (i>200 || text.charAt(i)!=' '))
        {
            build.append(text.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        return build.toString();
    }

Comment: oh sorry i made text=text.replace('n',' ') istead of lain text.replace. But now it is giving me only one word;/

Comment: Do not know why i used there string builder.... Long day, short night.... But thank you for your help!